# Powershell using string and file content in email message body without breaking formatting

Tags: powershell

I have a Powershell script that has a part which needs to email some information. I have a requirement to include 2 pieces of information inside the message body, but I am having issues with formatting. The first part will be a line of text which I would like to simply store inside the powershell script as a variable, and the second part will be information from a text file. Below is a simplified version of what I want to do:

```
$INFO1="The following fruits are ready to eat:


"
$INFO2=get-content "info2.txt"
$BODY=$INFO1 + $INFO2
$BODY=$BODY | out-string
send-mailmessage -To myname@mydomain.com -Subject "Fruit Status" -From 
fruit@mydomain.com -Body $BODY -Smtpserver smtp.mydomain.org -UseSsl
```

The file info2.txt contains the following info. 3 columns with a list of fruits with tab separators:

```
Col1        Col2        Col3
Apple       Orange      Pear
Banana      Grape       Strawbery
Kiwi        Peach       Apricot
```

The above code works but I get an email which looks like this:

```
The following fruits are ready to eat:


Col1        Col2        Col3 Apple      Orange      Pear Banana     Grape       
Strawbery Kiwi      Peach       Apricot
```

It keeps the line spaces in the $INFO1 stored variable string, but then places the content of the info2.txt file all in one continuous line, with no line breaks or tabbed formatting.

I tested this with the below changes whereby the line of text from the $INFO1 variable, is instead obtained by doing a get-content on the same piece of text from inside a file named "info1.txt". When I then append both pieces of information into the message body, the formatting is maintained and the email looks ok.

```
$INFO1=get-content "info1.txt" 
$INFO2=get-content "info2.txt"
$BODY=$INFO1 + $INFO2
$BODY=$BODY | out-string
send-mailmessage -To myname@mydomain.com -Subject "Fruit Status" -From 
fruit@mydomain.com -Body $BODY -Smtpserver smtp.mydomain.org -UseSsl



The following fruits are ready to eat:


Col1        Col2        Col3 
Apple       Orange      Pear 
Banana      Grape       Strawbery 
Kiwi        Peach       Apricot*
```

I also notice that if I do the below using the first method, grabbing the file content first and THEN the string from variable, the formatting is also kept fine:

```
$BODY=$INFO2 + $INFO1
```

It is only when I start with the string from variable first, that it mucks up the formatting in the email for the file content part.

I would prefer to keep the script more compact and minimize writing out to files on disk and used stored variables. Is there a way I can use method 1 appending a string or multiple strings, followed by file content where formatting is kept? I do not wish to use HTML for this as it will overly complicate matters with the text file content I am working with so the body is just -body  rather than -bodyashtml unless this is the only way to sort this.

Comment: I assume your tabular data is in $INFO2.  Could you share what $Info2 looks like if you ran a write-host against it?  Also, can you clearly highlight your question?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found the answer. I played with the get-content -RAW argument before but I think I was having trouble using it to get content stored in the pipeline. When I use it as below directly on a file with no other where clauses, it fixes the issue:

```
$INFO1="The following fruits are ready to eat:


"
$INFO2=get-content "info2.txt" -raw
$BODY=$INFO1 + $INFO2
$BODY=$BODY | out-string
send-mailmessage -To myname@mydomain.com -Subject "Fruit Status" -From 
fruit@mydomain.com -Body $BODY -Smtpserver smtp.mydomain.org -UseSsl
```

> Get-Content gets the content of the item at the location specified,
>   such as the text in a file.  By default PowerShell will read the
>   content one line at a time and return a collection of System.String
>   objects.  Carriage returns (CR/LF) are stripped from the original file
>   but when PowerShell displays a collection of strings, it will
>   re-insert carriage returns so that the display will look just like the
>   original file.
>
> If you specify -raw, this behaviour is reversed and the entire file
>   will be read at once.

Comment: Your "problem" was because of the string on the LHS of this operation `$BODY=$INFO1 + $INFO2`. `$info2` was converted to a string and arrays are flattened as strings delimited by spaces. By making info2 a single string it avoids that issue. `get-content "info2.txt" | Out-String` or ``(get-content "info2.txt") -join "`r`n"`` would also have worked